# Pass array value to modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using [Modal plugin from Twitter Boostrap JS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal) to display modals in my Project. I am displaying Messages using PHP and Database. The messages have "reply" and "delete" option(One modal for each). I want to Pass array id into these modal.How can i do that?

Here my Displaying Code:

```
<p><?php echo $row['message'];?></p>
<input type="hidden" id="msgid" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">
<a href="#replyModal" data-toggle="modal" class="reply-to"><i class="icon-share-alt"></i>Reply</a>
<a href="#deletemodal" data-toggle="modal" class="reply-to"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</a>
```

I want id to be passed into modals.So that i can take action on it.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="replyModal">
<form action="replymsg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-header">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
<h3>Reply:</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<input type="text" id="msgid"></input>
<textarea name="message" style="width:98%; height:100px;"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post Reply</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: How-to questions are generally discouraged.  See the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Sorry for Posting a How to.But, you can do nothing if there is no solution for your question on the web.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple. You actually just mode the hidden input into the modal form and there you go. You got the ID when it posts.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="replyModal">
    <form action="replymsg.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="msgid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h3>Reply:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <textarea name="message" style="width:98%; height:100px;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post Reply</button>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

If you do not have access for the modal window in your PHP for some reason then use jQuery to on click of the a tag set the id of the row to delete on a hidden input field inside the form within the modal popup.

-

**Edit - Added JavaScript example**
 - Test: http://jsfiddle.net/3A7Mg/  *(This only shows you if you inspect the modal div that when you click on the reply link it adds a hidden input field to it.)*

**Use JavaScript below:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.reply-to').click(function (e) {
        var $exists = $('#replyModal form input#dbid');

        if($exists.length == 0) {
            $('#replyModal form').prepend('<input type="hidden" id="dbid" name="dbid" value="'+$('#msgid').val()+'" />');
        } 
    });
});
```

Then when the user submit the form you will in PHP POST have a index named "dbid" as so:

```
$_POST['dbid']
```

​

Comment: Hi Dannie, Thanks for your answer. Yes, i don't have access to PHP in modal. I am not much experienced in jquery. Can you please enlighten me on this?

Comment: Added a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Dannie, Thanks for the Solution. I am now getting id in Modal. But, the problem is i have array of "messages" with unique id attached to it. This javascript is grabbing only the first id. Please help.Thanks again!

Comment: Hackopedia, if you have a array if ID's you want to have passed on then join the ID list with a comma. For an example: array(1,2,3) becomes: 1,2,3    - Then in php you can just make a compile method that takes a string. Explode on "," and loop the items. If item is a number add to array. Aaaand now you have the ID list you started with:) - Sry for the late response. Been too busy the past weeks.

Comment: Thanks Dannie..Your Solution is helpful.